# TypeScript - ¿Llamadas a funciones sin paréntesis?

Tags: funciones, typescript

Soy relativamente nuevo a TypeScript y estoy revisando tanto la [`documentación oficial`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html) como los ejemplos de [`GitHub`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/).

En uno de estos ejemplos de GitHub hay una función `uri` a la que se le pasan los argumentos sin usar paréntesis ([`ejemplo completo`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/master/async/src/lib/github.ts)):

```
public async getRateLimit() {
    return this.get<RateLimit>(uri`/rate_limit`);
}
```

Aquí se muestra la implementación de esta función :

```
function uri(template: TemplateStringsArray, ...args: any[]): string;
function uri(template: TemplateStringsArray) {
    let text = template[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < template.length; i++) {
        text += encodeURIComponent(String(arguments[i]));
        text += template[i];
    }
    return text;
}
```

No logro ver esta forma de llamar a las funciones docmentada por ningún sitio.
Agradecería mucho un link a la documentación o una explicación si estoy equivocado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esto no es un *feature* de Typescript como tal sino de ECMAScript 6 llamada [*tagged template literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) o [*plantillas de cadena de texto con postprocesador*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings).

> Una forma más avanzada de plantillas de cadenas de texto son aquellas que contienen una función de postprocesado. Con ellas es posible modificar la salida de las plantillas, usando una función. El primer argumento contiene un array con las cadenas de texto de la plantilla. El segundo y subsiguientes argumentos con los valores procesados ( ya cocinados ) de las expresiones de la plantilla. Finalmente, la función devuelve la cadena de texto manipulada. El nombre de la función no es nada especial, se puede usar cualquier nombre de función en su lugar.

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

function procesador(cadenas, ...valores) {
  console.log('Texto:', cadenas);
  console.log('Valores interpolados:', valores);

  return "La salida es " + valores.join(',');
}

console.log(procesador `Texto ${ a + b } entrada ${ a * b}`);
```

Usualmente los desarrolladores de Typescript tratan de soportar lo más posible los features del lenguaje nativo ya que Typescript siempre compila a javascript por lo que no sería buena idea eliminar *features* del lenguaje base. Esta es una cita de una [vieja noticia](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/01/16/announcing-typescript-1-4/) pero te da idea de los objetivos de los que desarrollan el lenguaje y en que versión ocurrió ese cambio

> En adición a la mejora del sistema de tipos, uno de los objetivos principales para el lanzamiento de TypeScript 2.0 es soportar completamente el estándard ECMAScript 6. Con TypeScript 1.4, tomamos otros pasos en este sentido. En esta versión hemos añadido un nuevo modo de salida para ES6, soporte para `let` y `const` y soporte para ES6 `template strings`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la explicación y el ejemplo! :)